# Orthogonality of Hermite Polynomials

Tags: mixture-distribution, polynomial

As we know probabilistic Hermite polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the weight function $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2}$ (density of standard normal).

I have a distribution which is a mixture of two Gaussians each having $(Mean, variance) =(1 ,\sigma^2)$   and $(-1,\sigma^2)$ respectively.

what are the changes we have to make ( In weight function and coefficients of Hermite polynomials) so that Hermite polynomials are orthogonal with respect to the mixture of two Gaussian distribution.

Comment: Please clarify: your question basically is asking how to change the "weight function" (among other things) in order to make Hermite polynomials orthogonal with respect to your mixture--which is a *fixed* weight function.  In short, you ask how to change something while leaving it fixed. That makes no sense.  What do you really need to do?

Comment: My question is, Is there any way to modify the Hermite polynomials so that they are orthogonal w.r.t the mixture.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "modify": there will be an orthogonal basis of polynomials relative to the mixture, but it would be a stretch to construe them as "modifications" of the Hermite polynomials.  They will be what they will be.  So is that what you're looking for: an orthogonal polynomial basis?

Comment: Can you please give the procedure to construct the orthogonal polynomials relative to mixture.

Comment: Use Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization of the monomials (or of any other basis, such as the Hermite polynomials). I posted an example [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19492/how-do-i-solve-n-simultaneous-equations-for-n-variables/19504#19504). That code--which is symbolic--embodies the mathematical principles. It also happens to be executable: if you change `limits` to range from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ and the kernel `k` to be the mixture PDF, then apply `Orthogonalize` to the list of polynomials in `vectors`, you will have an answer.

Comment: What a wonderful piece of exposition at the link.